# Can a Kindle Paperwhite show metadata?

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, metadata

Can a Kindle Paperwhite show you the metadata on an e-book?  I do not mean to edit the metadata, but just to see it.  Or does just seeing the metadata already require special software like Calibre?

Or alternatively, can you see the metadata by connecting the Kindle to a PC, but without using editing software like Calbre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only metadata that is visible to the user in a Kindle Paperwhite is the title and author of the ebooks.

Connecting the Kindle to a PC does only help if you synced your Kindle with Calibre's library, because in this case you would have in the root folder of your Kindle a file called `metadata.calibre` that would contain the metadata of your ebooks in YAML format.